Relative boundary equality for empty boundary set

I'm stuck with the following topology statement. I found it in a paper but I hope I've summarized all the necessary information to prove it.
Let's suppose to have a topological space $X$, a closed subspace $Y$. Let $C\subset Y$ such that $\partial_Y C=\emptyset$, which means that it is open in $Y$ and therefore exists a certain $W\subset X$ open in  $X$ that satisfies  $W\cap Y =C$.
We want to prove that we can choose $W$ in such a way that $(\partial_X W)\cap Y = \emptyset$.
Let me note that this exercise would be trivial if we knew that  $Y$ were open, which is not, because in that case we could just apply the formula found here.
I don't think this will be necessary but, just in case, we know also that $X$ is a metric space.
